# UIActivityViewController share UIActivity not shown

Tags: iphone, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity

I am using `UIActivityViewController` for camera roll image sharing:

```
UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

If I don't setup Facebook, and Twitter setting, I cannot find Facebook, Twitter, Message activities from `UIActivityViewController`.

Someone said the user should config Facebook and Twitter setting first, but I can find these activities from Apple camera app image sharing `UIActivityViewController` before configuring FB, Twitter setting.
And I cannot see Message activity anyhow.

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Try `UIActionSheet` instead.

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Share your photo" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Email",@"Facebook",@"Twitter",@"Instagram",@"Save to Photo Library",nil];
 [actionSheet showInView:self.view];

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(buttonIndex == 0){
      //for Email in code above
    }
}
```

Comment: UIActionSheet not support social sharing.